# Why defragging should be manually started in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, defragment

Why we have to manually start the disk defragmenter in Windows XP?.

Answer (score 6):

Because it is very disk intensive and it can slow down your system a lot. If an operating system did that without my intention I wouldn't buy it.

Although if you want you can schedule it to run.

Comment: I guess you'll never buy Vista or Windows 7. They both defragment in the drive in the background. The trick is that they only do it when your computer is idle.

Comment: Let me rephrase: If an operating system defragged while I was using the computer, I would not buy it. No computer near me is ever idle ;)

Comment: I hate hearing the hard drive working, when I'm trying to.

Comment: Same, if my machine suddenly starts thrashing the HDD, I wonder what's wrong, and go to find out what the hell it's doing..

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to. You can make the computer automatically start it for you.

[Here's Microsoft's page on how schedule defragmentation with XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/learnmore/tips/gehrke1.mspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you use JKDefrag or [Mydefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/) you can set defragmentation as your screensaver and it will start whenever your not busy. That solves all your problems!

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

- [defraggler](http://www.defraggler.com/)

Allows you to select **individual** files to defrag, can be configured to execute in the background, can be scheduled to run automatically at specific times.